# I have no idea why I'm getting the errors I'm getting

Tags: c, cryptography

Here is my code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> // this means I also need -lm at the execution of my code

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
        return 1;

    const char salt[] = {argv[1][13], argv[1][12]}; // the value of salt is the first two chars in string argv[1], and the length of the hash is always 13

   // This was const char key[9] and accounted for 8 of the errors
   char key[9]; // create array of size 9 since one of the values is the null char

    long long int i = 32; // initialize the incrementing variable at the lowest value printable ASCII character; long long because it's going to reach very high numbers
    int j = (((i - 32))/95); // digit for key 1
    int k = ((i - 32)/pow(95,2)); // digit for key 2
    int l = ((i - 32)/pow(95,3)); // digit for key 3
    int m = ((i - 32)/pow(95,4)); // digit for key 4
    int n = ((i - 32)/pow(95,5)); // digit for key 5
    int o = ((i - 32)/pow(95,6)); // digit for key 6
    int p = ((i - 32)/pow(95,7)); // digit for key 7

    while(i < pow(95,8) + pow(95,7) + pow(95,6) + pow(95,5) + pow(95,4) + pow(95,3) + pow(95,2) + 95) // this is inefficient but goes through every combination & string length
    {
        key[0] = ((i - 32) % 95) + 32;
        key[1] = (j % 95) + 32;
        key[3] = (k % 95) + 32;
        key[4] = (l % 95) + 32;        
        key[5] = (m % 95) + 32;
        key[6] = (n % 95) + 32;
        key[7] = (o % 95) + 32;
        key[8] = (p % 95) + 32;

        if(char *crypt_r(const char *key, const char *salt, struct crypt_data *data) == argv[1]) // compare the hash of the current key string to the inputted hash
        {
            printf("%s\n", key);
            return 0; //print password and exit
        }

        else // if the hashes don't match, then increment and try again
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The point of the problem is to receive any hashed password that's been hashed using C's DES-based crypt function and use brute force to figure it out.

The problem is that when I try to compile, I get 9 errors.  I'm using

```
 clang -o crack crack.c -lcrypt -lm
```

Eight of them are from `key[] =`*`something`*, and they say that the "read only variable is not assignable".

The last one has an issue with the "if" statement at the end with the char in it, and it puts an arrow below char and says "expected expression". I've spent hours on this code, and I'd really appreciate some help with it.

Note: I am a student, and so it's much more helpful for explanations instead of "here you go I fixed your code". It's also against the rules for this assignment, and I will be linking the post to my assignment since the course mandates I recognize any additional help I received outside of the course's teaching fellows and instructive materials.

EDIT: I changed the key[] and made it not constant, which fixed 8 of the errors. The last one with "expected expression" remains.

Comment: you declared `key` as a constant, then try to assign values to it. e.g. you're taking a constant and trying to treat it as a variable.

Comment: The initialization of variables `j..p` is `0` no need for the expression `(i-32)/pow(95,...)`

Comment: Are you sure I don't need the expression? I made them in order to increment them as i grew bigger.

Comment: I don't say you don't needed, i say it's the same that write `int j = 0; ...`. Most probably the initialization is wrong.

Comment: clang does tell you exactly what you are doing wrong. What else to you need?

Comment: I'm absolutely lost as to what I should do for the last error...

Comment: the lines containing: ((i - 32)) will start at 0 and increment with each pass of the while() loop.  However, such small numbers are divided by a very large number, using an integer divide, so all the variables j...p will be 0 for a very large number of itterations of the while() loop, then they will be 1 for another very large number of itterations of the while() loop, etc.

Comment: the char array k[] is trying to be set by integer (calculated) values.  (the compiler warnings should have told you that).  I suggest anding those calculated values with 0xFF and casting to char then make the assignments.

Comment: the adding of '+ 32' is effectively adding 0x2F to the values.  This is unlikely to result in printable characters.  Perhaps you meant 0x30?

Comment: The array k[] needs a '\0' terminator in the last position, other wise printf("%s", k) will not know when to stop printing characters.  you mention the need for a termination char in the declaration of k[] but do not actually put any termination char into the array.  k[8] IS the final array entry, and the code is putting (p % 95) + 32; into that location.

Comment: the line beginning with: while(i < pow(95,8) will overflow a int value, resulting in undefined behaviour.  perhaps a long long int should be used.

Comment: as another poster mentioned, the initialization of j...p will be 0 due to the integer divide operation.  Those same variables are never incremented/changed, so every iteration through the while() loop will result in the k[1]...k[8] being set to 0.

Comment: regarding your comment: I'm absolutely lost as to what I should do for the last error...  Which line is the compiler saying has the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
if(char *crypt_r(const char *key, const char *salt, struct crypt_data *data) == argv[1]) // compare the hash of the current key string to the inputted hash
```

It looks like you copied the declaration for `crypt_r` instead of calling the function. The difference is that the declaration tells you what the function is, and when you call it, you need to fill everything in.

For example, if you have:

```
char* key;
char* salt;
struct crypt_data* data;
// initialize all of those
```

Then you would call it like:

```
char* result = crypt_r(key, salt, data);
```

---

In general, if you have a function in the form:

```
some_type function_name(another_type parameter_name);
```

Then the function returns a `some_type` and expects an `another_type` as the first parameter. You don't need to redeclare the whole thing, you just need to give it the two things it wants:

```
another_type x = whatever;
some_type result = function_name(x);
```

Comment: Whoa, I totally got that wrong. I definitely know what you mean now though. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your program.

Comment: question: is there a difference between char key[] and char* key[]? I know char* means it's using pointers, but apart from that.

Comment: Yes, `char key[]` is an array of characters, while `char * key[]` is an array of pointers to characters (usually a pointer to a character is a string, so this would be an array of strings). You might want to read this: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html